# Any way to pass a variable to a function without using parameters?

Tags: python, parameter-passing

I'm trying to make an alarm clock in Python. The problem I'm having lies in the `displayTime` function. It's supposed to count down the number of seconds until the alarm will go off.

I need the `aTime` variable to be passed into the `displayTime` function. However, if I make `aTime` a parameter of the `displayTime` function, then I can't use `displayTime` as a parameter for `timelabel.after(timelabel.after(1000, displayTime(aTime)))`, as it will make it an instance of `displayTime` rather than a parameter.

Since `displayTime` is nested within the `alarm` function, why doesn't it inherit `aTime` from `alarm()`?

Also how else can I get `aTime` into `displayTime`? Is there any other way besides using a parameter?

Here is the code:

```
from Tkinter import *
import time

def alarm() :
    cHours = float(nHours.get())
    cHours = cHours * 3600
    cMinutes = float(nMinutes.get())
    cMinutes = cMinutes * 60
    aTime = cHours + cMinutes
    print aTime
    def displayTime():
        timelabel = Label(alarmGUI, text = "%d seconds until it's time to wake up" % aTime)
        timelabel.grid(row=9, column=0)
        aTime -=1
        timelabel.after(1000, displayTime)
    displayTime()

alarmGUI = Tk()
alarmGUI.geometry('500x400')
alarmGUI.title("Alarm Clock")

nHours = IntVar()
nMinutes = IntVar()

label1 = Label(alarmGUI, text = "Enter the number of hours and number of minutes that you want to sleep").grid(row=1, column=1)
label2 = Label(alarmGUI, text = "Hours").grid(row = 3, column = 0)
label3 = Label(alarmGUI, text = "Minutes").grid(row = 5, column = 0)

hours = Entry(alarmGUI, textvariable = nHours).grid(row = 3, column = 1)
minutes = Entry(alarmGUI, textvariable = nMinutes).grid(row = 5, column = 1)

button1 = Button(alarmGUI, text = "Start", command = alarm).grid(row = 7, column = 0)
alarmGUI.mainloop()
```

Comment: What do you mean *"inherit"*? `displayTime` doesn't *subclass* `alarm`, it's just nested inside it. Also, note that you've made a classic `Tkinter` error - `Widget(...).grid(...)` will `return None`, so all of your references won't work.

Comment: You _can_ pass a function object as a parameter. Just use the function name; don't call it.

Comment: I thought that since it was nested inside it would have access to the variables inside alarm, I guess that only works for subclasses though.

Comment: @tyteen4a03 if I do that, then I get an error.
    
    TypeError: displayTime() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)   
I thought it was because it didn't get passed the aTime parameter when displayTime is used as a parameter for the after function. Am I wrong or is that what the error is for?

Comment: Just remove the braces. Use only `displayTime`